# Scroll to UITableViewCell from String

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct, tableview

I want to automatically scroll to a UITableViewCell. I know how to do this by the row number like

```
var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRowYouWant, inSection: 0)
self.tableview.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, 
               atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
```

But, I want to scroll to the cell that equals a string. I have a struct

```
struct Song {
    var title: String
    var artist: String
}

var songs: [Song] = [
    Song(title: "Title 1", artist "Artist 1"),
    Song(title: "Title 2", artist "Artist 2"),
    Song(title: "Title 3", artist "Artist 3"),
]
```

And the `UITableViewCell`'s title is equal to the `title` and the `subtitle` is equal to the artist. Whenever a user taps on a UIButton, I want it to scroll to the cell that is `Song(title: "Title 3", artist "Artist 3")`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When they press the button, simply loop through your songs array and check for the song that has the given title and artist you're looking up.  When you find it, scroll to the cell whose index path aligns with the index in the array you found that song at.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: @JacobCavin Um I just explained it i'm not sure what you need clarification on.  Whatever button you have would just have a click event where you would loop through your Song array and check each one until you find the Song you're looking for.  Once you do you take whatever index in the array that's at and use that scrollToRowAtIndexPath method on that index.  The indices should line up if you populate your tableview by taking the indexPath.row in your cellForRowAtIndexPath and using it as the index to pull info from your song array for that cell.

Answer (score -1):

Add a property to your **Song** class like this:

```
struct Song {
var title: String
var artist: String
var idOrder: Int
}
```

Then you have to order your songs in your list by idOrder. idOrder is also your row's number and so you can use your code:

```
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRowYouWant, inSection: 0)
    self.tableview.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(song.idOrder, 
               atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
```